# How to reduce space between a text line and differents \hline in a table - trying to use negative \vspace value

Tags: tables, spacing, color, french, hline

On the following figure, I try to make decrease the space betwen the line "**Nombre de bins : (Y1) :5 ...**" and the two \hlines above.

More over, you can see that line "**Nombre de bins : (Y1) :5 ...**" is not very well filled since a slight vertical shift in upward direction.

[image: space too big between bottom lines and above \hline]

Here's the code snippet :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\small
\centering
\vspace{0.3cm}
\label{tab:lsst-specifications}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\rowcolor{jonquil} & Param\`etre  & Valeur \\
\hline\hline \\ 
Surface du Survey dans le ciel & $A_{\rm survey}$  & $20,000\,\deg^2$ \\
Erreur sur le redshift Weak Lensing (Y1 et Y10) : & $\sigma_{z}$ & $0.05(1+z)$ \\
Erreur sur le redshift GC photom\'etrique (Y1 et Y10) : & $\sigma_{z}$ & $ 0.03(1+z)$ \\
Redshift minimal et maximal des \'echantillons (Y1 et Y10) : & $[z_{\rm min},z_{\rm max}]$  & $[0.2,1.2]$ \\
\hline\hline \\
\vspace{-0.5cm} \\
\rowcolor{jonquil}Nombre de bins : (Y1) : 5 ($\Delta z = 0.2$) ; (Y10) : 10 ($\Delta z = 0.1$) & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Sp\'ecifications pour le survey LSST.}
\label{specLSST}
\end{table}
```

1) As you can see, I tried to use a `\vspace{-0.5cm}` to get the bottom text to the upward direction but without success.

2) I also tried to use the option : `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-0.05cm}`
   but it doesn't seem to have an effect expected.

Anyone has an idea about this issue ?

Comment: you should not have `\\ ` after `\hline` that is causing a spurious empty row.

Comment: Unrelated, do not use `\rm` in latex, you can use `\min` to get a min operator in roman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, there should be no `\\` (double backslash) directives after the `\hline\hline` directives. If you want to give the table a more open "look", load the `array` package and issue an instruction such as `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`.
- Since you're using color to create visual offset, you shouldn't mix-and-mismatch visual metaphors by using horizontal black lines as well. (Either use colored rows or horizontal lines, *but not both*.) I suggest you omit the `\hline` directives entirely.
- Since your document's language appears to be french, you can make life easy (or easier) on yourself by loading the `babel` language with the option `french`. E.g., spacing around characters such as `:` and `;` will be handled automatically.
- If you load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`, you can enter accented characters such as `à`, `ç`, `é`, `è`, `ê` and `ù` directly -- really no need to create them via escape-character sequences.
- To typeset scientific units and their associated quantities, do load the `siunitx` package and use the macros `\SI` and `\si`. That way, you also don't have to worry about excess whitespace after the `,` (comma) characters that function as thousands separators. (I noticed the gap between `20,` and `000` right away when I looked at the screenshot you posted. Really!)
- Since you use a `table` environment, it makes little to no sense to use a `\captionof` directive. Simply use `\caption`. And don't use two `\label` directives in a `table`. There should only be one `\label` statement -- the one *after* the `\caption` directive.
- Don't use `A_{\rm survey}` -- `\rm` has been deprecated and no longer works in some LaTeX document classes. Instead, write `A_{\mathrm{survey}}`. Or, `z_{\min},z_{\max}` to get upright lettering.

The following example implements these suggestions. (I used yellow since I don't know how the color "jonquil" is defined.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{colortbl} % for \rowcolor macro
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[locale=FR,group-separator={,}]{siunitx} % for \SI and \si macros

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\small % is it needed?
\centering
%\vspace{0.3cm} % why?
%%\label{tab:lsst-specifications} % don't provide 2 \label statements 
\begin{tabular}{lll}
%\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} & Paramètre  & Valeur \\
%\hline\hline  
Surface du Survey dans le ciel 
   & $A_{\mathrm{survey}}$  & \SI{20000}{\deg\squared} \\
Erreur sur le redshift Weak Lensing (Y1 et Y10): 
   & $\sigma_{z}$ & $0.05(1+z)$ \\
Erreur sur le redshift GC photométrique (Y1 et Y10): 
   & $\sigma_{z}$ & $ 0.03(1+z)$ \\
Redshift minimal et maximal des échantillons (Y1 et Y10): 
   & $[z_{\min},z_{\max}]$  & $[0.2,1.2]$ \\
%\hline\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} 
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Nombre de bins: (Y1): 5 ($\Delta z = 0.2$); 
   (Y10): 10 ($\Delta z = 0.1$)} \\ 
%\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Spécifications pour le survey LSST.}
\label{specLSST}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```